Source of Taylor's "equation of state for a perfect gas"
What is the derivation of Taylor's "equation of state for a perfect gas  (10)" in his 1941 paper?

What does it even mean?

The combination of derivatives in front is the convective derivative, which gives the rate of change of a quantity as you follow a piece of gas in its flow. The quantity being differentiated is $p/\rho^\gamma$ which is the quantity which is conserved when an ideal gas exchanges no heat with its environment (an adiabatic process).

I see you asked a related question about this paper earlier; the true answer to both is that you should learn from a regular fluid dynamics textbook, because research papers aren't written to be learned from. Any standard introduction should be enough to understand the paper.

Can you please cite your "regular fluid dynamics textbook". I am unable to find that derivation in any of mine (Batchelor, Landau& Lifshitz, Bennett, Faber or Kundu) . (And yes, I did ask a similar question earlier, but have only received   similar dismissive responses)

For example, it's on page 3 of Landau, specifically by combining equation 2.5 ("$ds/dt = 0$") with the definition of entropy of an ideal gas.

The equations in the first few pages are not in the exact same form as in the paper you cite, but they mean the same thing, and if you understand the first ~4 pages of Landau thoroughly you'll be able to convert them into the paper's work.

I am looking for a derivation of Taylor's (10), and you're saying: "you'll be able to convert them into the paper's work". If I could, I would have done. Are you able to do the conversion, or could you direct me to one?

This answer is intended to show how to use resources helpfully suggested by knzhou, Chet, and Shaktyai—along with the source material—to explicate the equation of interest,
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)(p\rho^{-\gamma})=0.$$
Rather than being "dismissive," the comments provide useful signposts of concepts to explore and link.
Taylor is discussing spherical explosions with distances measured over a radial coordinate $r$; $p$, $\rho$, and $u$ are defined as the pressure, density, and radial velocity, respectively, and $\gamma$ is defined as the heat capacity ratio.
The equation applies an operator $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)$ to an operand $(p\rho^{-\gamma})$ and sets the result to zero.
Somebody mentioned the Navier–Stokes equations. We find many examples of the form $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\boldsymbol u\cdot \nabla\right)$ on that page and determine that this is the material or convective derivative associated with a continuity equation, with both terms mentioned in existing comments. In some region, the rate of increase $\left(\frac{\partial()}{\partial t}\right)$ of some conserved quantity plus the
the rate of convective exit of that thing $(\boldsymbol u\cdot \nabla())$ must equal zero, with full discussion and visualization in the links. (A review of vector operators such as the divergence is helpful here.) The first few pages of Fluid Mechanics by Landau & Lifshitz, also mentioned in a comment, introduces another useful interpretation: If fluid movement reduces the amount of a conserved quantity at some fixed point $\left(\frac{\partial()}{\partial t}<0\right)$, then the gradient of that quantity in a fixed coordinate system must be positive in the direction of fluid motion $(\boldsymbol u\cdot \nabla()>0)$, with the two terms canceling out.
The gradient $\nabla$ for spherical symmetry is just $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$, and $u$ is the radial component of velocity $\boldsymbol{u}$, so we have identified and interpreted the operator in the equation.
What is being conserved? Somebody mentioned entropy and
adiabatic processes. An explosion is rapid, and Taylor states an adiabatic condition, there being no time for heat transfer—i.e., entropy transfer—in or out of some amount of material. In the lack of dissipative processes, the entropy generation is also taken as zero.
The change in entropy of a perfect gas is $$\Delta S=Nk\ln\left[\left(\frac{T}{T_0}\right)^{\hat c_V}\left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right)\right]=Nk\hat c_V\ln\left[\left(\frac{p}{p_0}\right)\left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right)^\gamma\right],\tag{1}$$
with amount $N$, Boltzmann's constant $k$, and dimensionless constant-volume heat capacity $\hat c_V$. (I've used the ideal-gas equation of state $PV=nRT$ and the definition of the heat capacity ratio to obtain the last term.) Evidently the conservation of entropy that Taylor assumes implies conservation of $pV^\gamma$ and thus conservation of $p\rho^{-\gamma}$, so we’ve identified  the operand in the equation.
To summarize:

A fast explosion is modeled using an adiabatic condition.
There are no dissipative processes in the participating ideal gas.
Since entropy can't enter through heat transfer or be generated through dissipative processes, the gas remains at constant entropy.
Constant entropy is shown in Eq. (1) above to imply constant $pV^\gamma$ (and thus constant $p\rho^{-\gamma}$ for some constant amount).
The conservation equation for constant $p\rho^{-\gamma}$ in a moving amount of fluid is $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\boldsymbol u\cdot \nabla\right)(p\rho^{-\gamma})=0$.
Since only radial motion is considered, the equation simplifies to $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)(p\rho^{-\gamma})=0$, the equation of interest.

In another question, you rejected a 2002 textbook recommendation as subsequent to Taylor's paper. But all of the above would have been known to Taylor. If you're more interested in what texts Taylor would have had on his desk at the time, you may find History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange to be useful.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
